# How to apply multiple conditions with in in a same column in a SQL table?

Tags: sql

[image: Image shows the Input table and expected result set]

I want to find the Emp_ID and Name who 'Skill' values should be 'DBA and Data Analytics'. 0My expected answer should be 1000(2 records),1005 (2 records).

I tried by applying the 'DBA' condition and then applying 'Data Analytics' .But in this case 1000,1002,1003,1005 records returned. But 1002 & 1003 should not come as my conditions is Skill should be 'DBA and Data Analytics' across all the Emp_id.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find the Emp_ID and Name who 'Skill' values should be 'DBA and Data Analytics'.

You can use `exists`:

```
select i.*
from input i
where i.skill in ('DBA', 'Data Analytics') and
      exists (select 1
              from input i2
              where i2.emp_id = i.emp_id and
                    i2.skill <> i.skill
             );
```